# Bootstrap disable view of phone/tablet

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

experts.

I´ve found no solution for this Problem. I used Bootstrap to Build up a template for me, but here´s the Problem:

I don´t want the site to get scaled (views for tablet or mobile)...

That means if the width of the screen is under i think 980px* it scales down.

> --> Short: How to disable the other views/scale down (phone/tablet) in Twitter Bootstrap?

thanks for reading/helping.

Comment: How are you accessing the bootstrap CSS? is it on twitters server or are you using a local copy?

Comment: local copy. All the js and css files are included.

Comment: You need to change in the CSS the parts that say `@media` I would comment them out or just remove then altogether. If you remove them make sure you keep a back up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't include `bootstrap-responsive.css` (or it's minified version) in your header, just `bootstrap.css` (or it's minified version).

A.k.a Locate these in your `<head>` and remove:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

`<link href="path/to/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">`

The `@media` queries that make the responsive layout are located in this css.

For more info, read http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: I´ll try that, thanks. I guess this should work, so i accept this.

Comment: @user777 Ok. Another tip is to use `container` and not `container-fluid` classes. The same applies for `row-fluid` (use `row`). Don't forget to click in the green tick if you confirm this is the answer you were looking for ;)

Comment: yeah i know ;) thank you very much ;) but i could´t accept, it was to early.